# how to manage IaC for single tenant self service clients?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

We are building a saas for single-tenant self-service clients (clients can register themselves).
Every client has its own resources (for example, AWS buckets, CloudFront distro, DNS records, EKS cluster).
Currently, we are managing it using Terraform and custom scripts, and manual work.

I'm looking for an automated process for it or a control plane guide.
I wonder how services like `mongo atlas`, `AWS rds`, and others are managing their infrastructure, where tools like Terraform are not enough (you just can't manage hundreds of clients manually updating files).